# More precision than double in swift

Tags: swift, floating-point, double

Are there are any floating points more accurate than `Double` available in Swift? I know that in C there is the `long double`, but I can't seem to find its equivalent in Apple's new programming language.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may be interested in https://gmplib.org/ ...

Comment: You may need to fall back on CoreFoundation types and use something like `CUnsignedLongLong`.

Comment: @JAL: CUnsignedLongLong is an *integral* type (a 64-bit integer), not a floating point type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is! There is `Float80` exactly for that, it stores 80 bits (duh), 10 bytes. You can use it like any other floating point type. Note that there are `Float32`, `Float64` and `Float80` in Swift, where `Float32` is just a typealias for `Float` and `Float64` is one for `Double`

Comment: Float80 is only available on the Mac

Answer (score 6):

Currently iOS 11+ runs on 64 Bit platform, **Double** holds Highest among all.

> Double has a precision of at least 15 decimal digits, whereas the
>   precision of Float can be as little as 6 decimal digits. The
>   appropriate floating-point type to use depends on the nature and range
>   of values you need to work with in your code. In situations where
>   either type would be appropriate, Double is preferred.

However in **CGFloat** The native type used to store the CGFloat, which is Float on 32-bit architectures and Double on 64-bit architectures

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html