# Get more than 15 decimal places Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, double

This is a pretty simple question. It appears to me that Doubles are capped at around 15 decimal places. For example, take the following code snippet:

```
var test : Double = 3.141592653589793238462643383279
```

Swift playgrounds shows this Double's value as 3.141592653589793. Is there any possible way that I can get more than 15 decimal places on a Double? From Apple's documentation, it sounds like it should be possible:

> Double has a precision of at least 15 decimal digits, whereas the
>   precision of Float can be as little as 6 decimal digits. The
>   appropriate floating-point type to use depends on the nature and range
>   of values you need to work with in your code. In situations where
>   either type would be appropriate, Double is preferred.

The part that says "at least" makes it appear that this is possible, but I can't find any method of doing so. I also know that it's not Swift Playgrounds simply truncating the value in the output. The following code returns true, even though the values are not the same, so it's clear that the double is only storing and comparing up to 15 decimal places:

```
var test : Double = 3.141592653589793238462643383279

var result = test == 3.1415926535897932384626433
```

Comment: "At least" means you may get one more decimal depending on magnitude and values. They may additionally be referring to the long double type, but I doubt it. Use a decimal or bignum type if you need more digits.

Comment: By "at least 15" they mean you might get 16. That's it for `Double`. Look at `NSDecimalNumber `/`Decimal` and get up to 38.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023561/more-precision-than-double-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

For greater precision use [Float80](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float80) `Type` (the first bit in this structure is used for sign):

```
Float80.exponentBitCount        // 15
Float80.significandBitCount     // 63

Double.exponentBitCount         // 11
Double.significandBitCount      // 52
```

[image]

Hope this helps.